# How to Name Manual Snapshots via Softlayer Python Lib

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was wondering how one could use the Softlayer API to Gather and Name manual snapshots using the [Softlayer_Network_storage service](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage)?

It's not clear what mask to use when using "getManualSnapshots" to view a name I've set for a manual snapshot.

[image: example of named snapshot]

Currently, my mask is as follows

```
 mask='mask[serviceResource[serviceResourceName]]'
```

but this is only yielding errors. Beyond this, I was not sure what else I could use to get the name.

I after I figured out what object ID contained the name, I was thinking that I would use the "editObject" attribute to edit the snapshots name, would this be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to get the notes,

```
mask=mask[notes]
```

and to add the name just edit the object and replace the note, you need to use this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/editObject

edit Object:

```
import SoftLayer
import json
import sys

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].editObject({"notes": "testing notes"},id=snapshot
_id)
```

Regards

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the editObject. 

Error: 
faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Server, faultString=Internal Error

-----code: 
    obj_template = {
        'notes': 'test'
    }

    try:
        snapshots = SL.instance(sl_config).storage_iscsi.editObject(obj_template, id=snapshot_id)

Comment: I was able to edit it, I updated my answer with the code

Comment: Is there a way to name snapshots  on creation.. aka without using the editObject. maybe somethign like "snapshots = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].createSnapshot( {"notes": "testing notes"}, id=iscsi_identifier)" I have tried this but that value "Array" is being assigned to the "notes" column

Comment: According documentation yes you can, http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/createSnapshot. your code is wrong you nedd to send a string and not a json object, change it like this client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].createSnapshot( "testing notes", id=iscsi_identifier)